# Docker build auth error

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to do a docker build from a Jenkins job and I am getting the below error. Any ideas what is causing this error.

```
11:10:32 Step 1 : FROM docker.xxxx.com/xx/pkg-ssl:7-jdk8
11:10:32 Get https://docker.xxxx.com/v2/xx/pkg-ssl/manifests/7-jdk8: 
  unauthorized: unable to get identity token from basic auth credentials: 
  invalid_grant: invalid authentication credentials given
11:10:32 Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
```

Comment: `invalid authentication credentials given` it seems like the credentials changed, try to `docker login` again

Comment: Thanks Julian. That seems to be the case.